# Pixel-perfect collisions in Monogame, with float positions

Tags: xna, collision-detection, monogame, 2d-games

I want to detect pixel-perfect collisions between 2 sprites.

I use the following function which I have found online, but makes total sense to me.

```
    static bool PerPixelCollision(Sprite a, Sprite b)
    {
        // Get Color data of each Texture
        Color[] bitsA = new Color[a.Width * a.Height];
        a.Texture.GetData(0, a.CurrentFrameRectangle, bitsA, 0, a.Width * a.Height);
        Color[] bitsB = new Color[b.Width * b.Height];
        b.Texture.GetData(0, b.CurrentFrameRectangle, bitsB, 0, b.Width * b.Height);

        // Calculate the intersecting rectangle
        int x1 = (int)Math.Floor(Math.Max(a.Bounds.X, b.Bounds.X));
        int x2 = (int)Math.Floor(Math.Min(a.Bounds.X + a.Bounds.Width, b.Bounds.X + b.Bounds.Width));

        int y1 = (int)Math.Floor(Math.Max(a.Bounds.Y, b.Bounds.Y));
        int y2 = (int)Math.Floor(Math.Min(a.Bounds.Y + a.Bounds.Height, b.Bounds.Y + b.Bounds.Height));

        // For each single pixel in the intersecting rectangle
        for (int y = y1; y < y2; ++y)
        {
            for (int x = x1; x < x2; ++x)
            {
                // Get the color from each texture
                Color colorA = bitsA[(x - (int)Math.Floor(a.Bounds.X)) + (y - (int)Math.Floor(a.Bounds.Y)) * a.Texture.Width];
                Color colorB = bitsB[(x - (int)Math.Floor(b.Bounds.X)) + (y - (int)Math.Floor(b.Bounds.Y)) * b.Texture.Width];

                if (colorA.A != 0 && colorB.A != 0) // If both colors are not transparent (the alpha channel is not 0), then there is a collision
                {
                    return true;
                }
            }
        }
        //If no collision occurred by now, we're clear.
        return false;
    }
```

(all the `Math.floor` are useless, I copied this function from my current code where I'm trying to make it work with floats).

It reads the color of the sprites in the rectangle portion that is common to both sprites.

This actually works fine, when I display the sprites at x/y coordinates where x and y are int's (`.Bounds.X` and `.Bounds.Y`):

[View an example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/u6W1i.gif)

The problem with displaying sprites at int's coordinates is that it results in a very jaggy movement in diagonals:

[View an example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/H83xc.gif)

So ultimately I would like to not cast the sprite position to int's when drawing them, which results in a smooth(er) movement:

[View an example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1kCLp.gif)

The issue is that the PerPixelCollision works with ints, not floats, so that's why I added all those Math.Floor. As is, it works in most cases, but it's missing one line and one row of checking on the bottom and right (I think) of the common Rectangle because of the rounding induced by Math.Floor:

[View an example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nSNoR.gif)

When I think about it, I think it makes sense. If x1 is 80 and x2 would actually be 81.5 but is 81 because of the cast, then the loop will only work for x = 80, and therefore miss the last column (in the example gif, the fixed sprite has a transparent column on the left of the visible pixels).

The issue is that no matter how hard I think about this, or no matter what I try (I have tried a lot of things) - I cannot make this work properly. I am almost convinced that x2 and y2 should have Math.Ceiling instead of Math.Floor, so as to "include" the last pixel that otherwise is left out, but then it always gets me an index out of the bitsA or bitsB arrays.

Would anyone be able to adjust this function so that it works when `Bounds.X` and `Bounds.Y` are floats?

PS - could the issue possibly come from BoxingViewportAdapter? I am using this (from MonoExtended) to "upscale" my game which is actually 144p.

Comment: The Bounds are measured in Pixels.And since there is no 0,2 pixels it does not really make sense to use float here. Is there a reason you want to use float instead of int?

Answer (score 0):

Remember, there is no such thing as a fractional pixel.  For movement purposes, it completely makes sense to use floats for the values and cast them to integer pixels when drawn. The problem is not in the fractional values, but in the way that they are drawn.

The main reason the collisions are not appearing to work correctly is the scaling.  The colors for the new pixels in between the diagonals get their colors by averaging* the surrounding pixels.  The effect makes the image appear larger than the original, especially on the diagonals.

*there are several methods that may be used for the scaling, bi-cubic and linear are the most common.

**The only direct(pixel perfect) solution is to compare the actual output after scaling. This requires rendering the entire screen twice, and requires the scale factor more computations.**  (not recommended)

Since you are comparing the non-scaled images your collisions appear to be off.

The other issue is movement speed.  If you are moving faster than one pixel per Update(), detecting per pixel collisions is not enough, if the movement is to be restricted by the obstacle. You must resolve the collision.

For enemies or environmental hazards your original code is sufficient and collision resolution is not required. It will give the player a minor advantage.

A simple resolution algorithm(see below for a mathematical solution) is to unwind the movement by half, check for collision. If it is still colliding, unwind the movement by a quarter, otherwise advance it by a quarter and check for collision.  Repeat until the movement is less than 1 pixel. This runs log of Speed times.

As for the top wall not colliding perfectly: If the starting Y value is not a multiple of the vertical movement speed, you will not land perfectly on zero.  I prefer to resolve this by setting the Y = 0, when Y is negative. It is the same for X, and also when X and Y > screen bounds - origin, for the bottom and right of the screen.

I prefer to use mathematical solutions for collision resolution.  In your example images, you show a box colliding with a diamond, the diamond shape is represented mathematically as the Manhattan distance(`Math.Abs(x1-x2) + Math.Abs(y1-y2))`. From this fact, it is easy directly calculate the resolution to the collision.

On optimizations:

Be sure to check that the bounding Rectangles are overlapping before calling this method.

As you have stated, remove all `Math.Floor`s, since, the cast is sufficient. Reduce all calculations inside of the loops not dependent on the loop variable outside of the loop.

The `(int)a.Bounds.Y * a.Texture.Width` and `(int)b.Bounds.Y * b.Texture.Width`   are not dependent on the x or y variables and should be calculated and stored before the loops. The subtractions 'y-[above variable]` should be stored in the "y" loop.

I would recommend using a bitboard(1 bit per 8 by 8 square) for collisions. It reduces the broad(8x8) collision checks to O(1). For a resolution of 144x144, the entire search space becomes 18x18.

Answer (score 0):

you can wrap your sprite with a rectangle and use its function called Intersect,which detedct collistions.

[Intersect - XNA](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.drawing.rectangle.intersect?view=netframework-4.7.2)

Comment: This isn’t pixel perfect collision detection unless your sprites are exact rectangles.